# How can I parse this list with pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to use `pyparsing` to parse a list with "section headers" and "items. In this example, the sections will be days, and the items will be grocery items we need to buy.

```
from pyparsing import *

input = """Monday
- eggs
- milk
Tuesday
- bread
- flour
"""

day = Word(alphas)("day")
item = Suppress("- ") + rest_of_line
items = OneOrMore(item)("items")
daily_shopping_list = OneOrMore(day + items)

print(daily_shopping_list.parse_string(input).asDict())
```

This returns `{'day': 'Tuesday', 'items': ['bread', 'flour']}`

The desired output is `{{'day': 'Monday', 'items': ['eggs', 'milk']}, {'day': 'Tuesday', 'items': ['bread', 'flour']}}`

Why is this code skipping Monday?

Thank you.

Edit: As Tim Roberts mentioned, dropping `.asDict()` produces a valid output:

`['Monday', ['eggs', 'milk'], 'Tuesday', ['bread', 'flour']]`

Comment: Your "desired output" is not valid Python.  The outer brackets would need to be `[]` making it a list, but `asDict` can't do that.  It can only return one entry for each name, so you only get the last one.  If you skip the `asdict`, you can do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great first project with pyparsing. There are some features that pyparsing offers that help in returning structured data like this.

First off, when you call `parse_string()`, it returns a pyparsing `ParseResults` https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html#pyparsing.ParseResults
object. If you print this out, you get:

```
result = daily_shopping_list.parse_string(input)
print(result)
['Monday', 'eggs', 'milk', 'Tuesday', 'bread', 'flour']
```

It *looks* like a list of strings, but has a lot more features.

The first thing to look at is to call the `dump()` method. This will list out the parsed strings, followed by an indented listing of named items.

```
print(result.dump())
['Monday', 'eggs', 'milk', 'Tuesday', 'bread', 'flour']
- day: 'Tuesday'
- items: ['bread', 'flour']
```

As Tim Roberts points out, the default for naming is similar to that for Python dicts: the last value stored is the one you end up with.

You are actually pretty close to getting the structured results you want. Add a pyparsing `Group` expression, changing this line:

```
daily_shopping_list = OneOrMore(day + items)
```

to this line:

```
daily_shopping_list = OneOrMore(Group(day + items))
```

This will create day-items groups, and after this change, `results.dump()` prints:

```
[['Monday', 'eggs', 'milk'], ['Tuesday', 'bread', 'flour']]
[0]:
  ['Monday', 'eggs', 'milk']
  - day: 'Monday'
  - items: ['eggs', 'milk']
[1]:
  ['Tuesday', 'bread', 'flour']
  - day: 'Tuesday'
  - items: ['bread', 'flour']
```

This is actually a `ParseResults` containing 2 `ParseResults`, one for each parsed `Group`. `dump()` shows the names that are available for accessing the named values. For instance, you can get the first day's values as:

```
results[0]["day"]
results[0]["items"]
```

like they are dicts. You can also treat them like attributes in an object (if the names are valid Python identifiers):

```
results[0].day
results[0].items
```

If you want them as dicts, then call `as_dict()` on each contained `ParseResults`:

```
print([day_list.as_dict() for day_list in result])
[{'day': 'Monday', 'items': ['eggs', 'milk']}, {'day': 'Tuesday', 'items': ['bread', 'flour']}]
```

If you want this as a nested dict, where each day name is the dict key to the sub-dict, you can have pyparsing use the first element in each group as a key by wrapping the `OneOrMore` expression in a pyparsing `Dict`:

```
daily_shopping_list = Dict(OneOrMore(Group(day + items)))
```

Now the first part of `results.dump()` shows these keys:

```
[['Monday', 'eggs', 'milk'], ['Tuesday', 'bread', 'flour']]
- Monday: ['eggs', 'milk']
  - day: 'Monday'
  - items: ['eggs', 'milk']
- Tuesday: ['bread', 'flour']
  - day: 'Tuesday'
  - items: ['bread', 'flour']
```

And you can use the day names as keys:

```
result["Monday"]["items"]
```

Now calling `result.as_dict()` will `pprint` as:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(result.as_dict())
{'Monday': {'day': 'Monday', 'items': ['eggs', 'milk']},
 'Tuesday': {'day': 'Tuesday', 'items': ['bread', 'flour']}}
```

Comment: Great answer! The reference to the docs is the cherry on top

Comment: Lots to digest here. Thank you. I'm still struggling a bit with getting the returrned ParseResults and knowing exactly what named items it contains. I may start a new question to drill into that.

Answer (score 2):

> The desired output is {{'day': 'Monday', 'items': ['eggs', 'milk']},
> {'day': 'Tuesday', 'items': ['bread', 'flour']}}

First of all, as mentioned by @TimRoberts in the comments, your desired output is invalid.

```
{{'day': 'Monday', 'items': ['eggs', 'milk']}, {'day': 'Tuesday', 'items': ['bread', 'flour']}}
```

This would be a `set` with `dict` as elements. **No can do**.

If you just type that in a Python console, you will get:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

But you probably meant a `list` of `dict` instead, and this is pretty much possible.

```
raw_list = daily_shopping_list.parse_string(input)
result = [dict(day=day, items=items) for day, items in zip(*[iter(z)]*2)]
print(result)

# [{'day': 'Monday', 'items': ['eggs', 'milk']}, 
#  {'day': 'Tuesday', 'items': ['bread', 'flour']}]
```

Comment: It works, but fortunately pyparsing doesn't make you go through all these list and dict constructors. Instead of just a raw list of dicts or strs, parse_string actually returns a pretty rich object of type ParseResults, which has properties of both lists and dicts.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in on this pyparsing question. I'm always happy to see others picking up on pyparsing.